# Регулярное выражение для цифр и символа pipe (труба) |

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как правильно составить регулярное выражение для проверки строи которая **может содержать только** цифры и **возможны(но не обязательны)** символы pipe (турба) "|"
пробовал так:

```
$an = '1|2|02932';

if (preg_match("/^0-9\|/",$an) == 0) {   echo 1; }
if (preg_match("/^0-9|/",$an) == 0) {    echo 1; }
if (preg_match("/^0-9 |/",$an) == 0) {   echo 1; }
 if (preg_match("/^0-9 ?|/",$an) == 0) {     echo 1; }
```

ни чего из этого не работает нормально, по моему этот символ забронирован как некое значение типа OR но почему то он не экранируется символом \
что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^[0-9]+\|` - вернет истину, если строка начинается с одной или более цифр за которыми следует символ `|`.

Чтобы убедиться, что строка состоит только из цифр и символов, (порядок не важен) подойдет такое выражение:

```
^[0-9\|]+$
```

Оно вернет истину, если строка от начала до конца будет содержать один или более символов из группы в квадратных скобках.

Comment: спасибо но как можно сделать что бы проверяло на то что бы строка состояла только из цифр и возможны были pipe , потому что он так же возвращает истину и при так '1|2|02932sasdasd' строке

Comment: Ответ отредактировал.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите проверить, состоит ли строка из одних только чисел, разделенных символом `|`, используйте

```
if (preg_match('~^\d+(?:\|\d+)*\z~', $an)) {
    echo 1;
}
```

Или, если числа могут быть дробными:

```
if (preg_match('~^([-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)(?:\|(?1))*\z~', $an)) {
    echo 1;
}
```

См. [демо выражения №1](https://regex101.com/r/8t0pc9/1) и [демо выражения №2](https://regex101.com/r/8t0pc9/2).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `(?:\|\d+)*` - 0 и более повторов последовательности `|` и 1+ цифр
- `\z` - абсолютный конец строки (сразу после не должно быть ничего, даже финального `\n`, `$` этого не обеспечивает).

Во втором шаблоне вместо `\d+` использован шаблон `([-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)` для нахождения дробного или целого числа, а `(?1)` повторяет этот шаблон (чтобы не писать одно и то же):

- `[-+]?` -  необязательный символ `-` или `+`
- `\d*` - 0 и более цифр
- `\.?` - необязательный символ `.`
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?` - буква `e` или `E`, затем необязательный символ `+` или `-`, а потом 1 и более цифр.